# How to restrict user action from email link without login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

As part of my app, users get to approve certain "requests" via email. Requests have their own model and therefore each has a unique id.

Users get an email with a named route in a link: 'approve/:id' where :id is the id of the request. The approve method then handles the approval logic, etc.

How can I prevent a user from approving requests made to other users without having the user login beforehand? Since the ids are freely displayed in the URL, I guess a GUID would be needed or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do that, then yes, you'd need a GUID of some sort. Perhaps a cryptographic hash of the user_id or email address(?). so you end up using `/approve/:id/:GUID`.

I'm surprised you don't want the user to login though, remember that if they login you can redirect them on to the approval automatically. Also if the cookie is still valid a user may already be logged in.

Comment: Indeed, perhaps 4-5 years ago when users' login cookies were not always permanent this would have been necessary. I will probably go the login route. I was thinking of a scenario were the user would be getting a lot of requests and would be able to quickly approve/disapprove without having the intermediate authentication step.